# Connecting self hosted node app to domain

Tags: web-hosting, dns, node-js, namecheap

I’m new to hosting my websites and thought I’d give a go at hosting my node js app to a domain so I have experience delivering a website. I’m new to this and hit a point I just don’t understand why it’s not working.

I was able to set up a raspberry pi running Ubuntu 21.10 and connect it to my wifi with a static ip using netplan. I then portforwarded it’s ip and I can connect to my node app by typing in my public ip as well as the port.

I have a domain on name cheap and have connected it using ddclient to update the ip but when I type in the domain I don’t see my app. I can still specify the public ip and port and that seems to work but I can’t get the domain to work at all. Have I missed a step or does anyone have any advice?

The IP address I’m using that works is 77.100.120.45:8080. It just displays a 404 page for just now but it works I just can’t wrap my head around this domain stuff

I have entered my dns records here if that is of any help. I can’t seem to access the page at all through the domain but some others can.

[image]

Comment: FYI, I get the exact same "Oops! We didnt find what you are looking for" result with `http://77.100.120.45:8080` and `http://jack-duffy.com:8080`.  It appears that you have two separate A records with different IP addresses defined when I look [here](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php?query=jack-duffy.com&rtype=ALL&dns=google).  One is your `77.100.120.45` and the other is `192.64.119.72`.

Comment: Interesting i can’t see anything at all on the domain link, I’ll look into the a addresses see if that’s the issue. Is there a way I can make it so I don’t need the domain and port?

Comment: If port forwarding on your router/firewall is setup properly, then you can forward port 80 to port 8080 and then you will be able to use an http URL without a port in the URL.  FYI, the static IP address you use in DNS for your domain needs to be the IP address of your router/firewall (whatever host is doing the port forwarding).

Comment: Yeah I have my raspberry pi set up with ddclient to update my dynamic ip to the DNS. I’ll look into redirecting the port I just put it on port 8080 for testing really and to see if I can host one not on 80 or 443. I don’t get where the second ip is coming from or why I can’t see the oops message through the link. I added photos of the A addresses to see if that helps